# Looking for instructions to a set with many different sized round cogwheels

Tags: set-identification, instructions

This bag came in a large box but the bags didn’t have identifiers ie: 1,2,3 and we lost the instructions. Two small bags came inside the larger bag.[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is set [11019-1 Bricks and Functions](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=11019-1&name=Bricks%20and%20Functions&category=%5BClassic%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)

[image]

Key parts:

14t plate gear ([35446](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=35446#T=C)) in Lime

Turntable Base ([61485](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=61485#T=C)) in White

and a 1x4 gear rack ([3743](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3743#T=C) or 4296) in White